# ExceptionDetailsProvider (in Asp Net Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, diagnostics

https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/082d505977d72c75b68935c93c21feded6928e5f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage

I wants to implement custom DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware since its a open source project i am not able to find implementation details for

```
private Task DisplayRuntimeException(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
{
            var request = context.Request;

            var model = new ErrorPageModel
            {
                Options = _options,
                ErrorDetails = _exceptionDetailsProvider.GetDetails(ex), // NEED SOURCE CODE
                Query = request.Query,
                Cookies = request.Cookies,
                Headers = request.Headers
            };

            var errorPage = new ErrorPage(model);
            return errorPage.ExecuteAsync(context);
}
```

Please provide the implementation details for

```
ErrorDetails = _exceptionDetailsProvider.GetDetails(ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore

Consist of complete implementation (a opensource project from microsoft).